# Bind multiple Bootstrap tooltips and popover in one DOM?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Is there a way to bind multiple tooltips and/or popovers to the same DOM?
For example, `<div class='multiple-tooltips-popovers'></div>`, it has a left side tooltip when mouse hovers on it and bottom side popover when mouse clicks the div. Or it will show both left and right sides tooltips when mouse hovers on the  DOM

Answer (score 0):

Download Knockout-Bootstrap and add the .js reference to your project.

[Knockout-Bootstrap](http://billpull.com/knockout-bootstrap/)

Add

`data-bind="tooltip: {title: 'Default tooltip'}"`

attribute to any DOM element for the bootstrap tooltip to display.

The same for popovers

`data-bind="popover: {template: 'popoverBindingTemplate', title: 'Oh Yea Binding'}"`

For more check out the documentation on the website.

Thanks

Comment: Don't add it to your project using Nuget as it will replace your bootstrap files. just download the 'knockout-bootstrap.min.js' direct from the site.

Comment: No. I mean binding TWO tooltips/popovers on the same DOM. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/qZkXP/44/ does not work for the first tooltip.